# Conflicts with global types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, global, declare, name-collision

I would like to use my own global types (without `import`, using `declare type`) in TypeScript. For example:

```
// File with global types.
declare type Function<TParameter, TResult> = (parameter: TParameter) => TResult

// Another file.
const someMethod = (callback: Function<number, string>) => { ... }
```

However, there is conflict (`TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Function'.`) because of `lib.es5.d.ts` or any external library. Is there any way to ignore existing `Function` declaration and use my own?

The only solution that I know is put all own types to namespace:

```
// File with global types
declare type MyTypes.Function<TParameter, TResult> = (parameter: TParameter) => TResult

// Another file.
const someMethod = (callback: MyTypes.Function<number, string>) => { ... }
```

Comment: You can exclude the default libs from the compiler with `--noLib`  and define your own types but this implies replacing all definitions .. (also ts depends on the existence of certain types so it might not with that specific type)

Comment: I think that you should change your type name it's a bad thing to try overriding ts libraries